# Just installed freya but dont know how to connect to WIfi

Tags: system-installation, wifi

When I click on the internet icon the WIFI option is not displayed .
The wired (Ethernet) option it is listed and I can connect just fine using a wired connection but don't know what to do about connecting to WIFI.
My WIFI works just fine on other devices.

I would appreciate any help.

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a1100000-a1101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: b0:5a:da:d5:6b:c4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
   ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 
 autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169
  driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2
   02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII
  speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:127 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1004000-a1004fff
 memory:a1000000-a1003fff
```

Comment: If your PC has a hardware switch for the wifi then check if its not turned off accidentally.

Comment: You have not provided any information about your hardware yet. Please add the output of `sudo lshw -C network` to your question text, otherwise answers are based on mere speculation.

Comment: @embik Posted the output to sudo lshw -C network bellow.

Comment: @uxaar: You have been asked to edit this into your question. Additionally, please provie the output in a readable format. You can use "Preformatted text" as format option for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to enable the closed-source wifi driver as that was the problem on my laptop.

To enable to closed-source driver, open the software center then Edit > Software Sources (in the top menu) and navigate to the Additional Drivers tab and enable your wifi driver.

The reason these drivers aren't enabled is because Ubuntu developers can't review / modify the source-code

Comment: That was the first thing i have done.I have checked the aditional drivers section but there were no drivers there whatsoever.That section was empty.Also in the "other software" section i have ticked all the packages.So that didn't help either.